# Lower bound for number of primes up to $x$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

It is possible to prove the statement that $\pi(x)$, the number of primes up to $x$ is bigger than $\sqrt x$ for $x \ge 3$, in an elementary way? More generally can we prove that for every $0<\epsilon<1$,
$$
x^\epsilon < \pi(x),
$$
for $x$ large enough, in an elementary way?

Comment: [Wojowu](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/127263/wojowu), in a comment to my answer, considers the PNT (Prime Number Theorem) to not be "elementary". As I considered it to be elementary, I used it. However, the only person that should really decide this issue is you. If you consider using PNT to not be elementary, please respond as such & I'll delete my answer. Also, you may wish to clarify what you mean by "elementary" so anybody else trying to answer your question will have a better idea of what they can, & cannot, use in their response. Thanks.

Comment: In case you're interested, regarding how "elementary" is generally defined with number theory & the PNT, please see my comment to Wojowu below.

Comment: Yes. I wanted a proof without using PNT, as in which can be done in couple of pages starting from scratch. Thanks!!

Comment: Thank you for responding. As I said I would, I have deleted my answer as it doesn't meet your conditions. I don't offhand know any way to prove what you want without using the PNT, or at least something closely related to it (which I assume is also not allowed), but I hope somebody else here can help you.

Comment: I am bothered with this because, this statement is much much weaker than PNT. So why can't we have an easier proof for this? :(

Comment: I am not an expert in number theory, so don't take my not knowing any method to imply there is no fairly easy way to do it without using the PNT. Perhaps somebody more knowlegeable in number theory can either provide you with such a proof, or more conclusively state there likely isn't any.